# Duplicate array being returned from firebase after HTTP.get in Angular service

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, http-get

I am seeing a duplicate array in my response from a HTTP get from a Firebase realtime database in an Angular web-app.

I have created a firebase realtime database with the following setup:

[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5sLN.png)

In my angular application I am performing a HTTP get to retrieve data from Firebase.

```
fetchEventsAdmin2() {
    return this.http
      .get<bookableEvent[]>(
        'https://ng-smile-for-life-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/events.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(bookableEvent => {
          return bookableEvent.map(bookableEvent => {
            return {
              ...bookableEvent,
              BookingDates: bookableEvent.bookingDates ? bookableEvent.bookingDates : []
            };
          });
        }),
        tap(bookableEvent => {
          this.admService.setBookableEvents(bookableEvent);
        })
      )
  }
```

I call setBookableEvents to populate the local instance.

```
 setBookableEvents(bkEvent: bookableEvent[]) {
    this.bookableEvents = bkEvent;
    this.bookingChanged.next(this.bookableEvents.slice());
  }
```

The model looks like the following:

```
import { bookingDates } from "../shared/booking-dates.model";

export class bookableEvent {
    public eventName: string;
    public eventType: string;
    public eventLocation: string;
    public eventImage: string;
    public eventDuration: string;
    public maxAttendees: number;
    public currentAttendence: number;
    public questions: string;
    public eventOnOff: boolean;
    public locationImage: string;
    public descInstr: string;
    public bookingDates: bookingDates[]

    constructor(eName: string, 
                eType: string, 
                eLoc: string, 
                eImage: string, 
                eDuration: string,
                maxAttends: number, 
                currentAttends: number, 
                questions: string,
                eventOnOff: boolean, 
                locImage: string, 
                eDescrInstr: string, 
                bookingDates: bookingDates[])
    {
        this.eventName = eName;
        this.eventType = eType;
        this.eventLocation = eLoc;
        this.eventImage = eImage;
        this.eventDuration = eDuration;
        this.maxAttendees = maxAttends;
        this.currentAttendence = currentAttends;
        this.questions = questions;
        this.eventOnOff = eventOnOff;
        this.locationImage = locImage;
        this.descInstr = eDescrInstr;
        this.bookingDates = bookingDates
    }
}
```

When I examine the content retrieved response from Firebase in the console log (see image below) there is a duplicate array, with an uppercase BookingDates array, that I have haven't declared anywhere! It doesn't make any sense to me. It this a firebase or Angular HTTP bug or I am going crazy? Any help much appreciated. I'm probably doing something stupid. Thank you.

[Duplicate Array console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQjpo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go ahead and suppose that the purpose of the `map` operator is to assign an empty array for the `bookingDates` in case it comes as `null` from the server. If that's the reason, then you could rewrite it like this:

```
fetchEventsAdmin2() {
    return this.http
      .get<bookableEvent[]>(
        'https://ng-smile-for-life-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/events.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(bookableEvents => bookableEvents.map(bookableEvent => ({
          ...bookableEvent,
          bookingDates: bookableEvent.bookingDates ?? []
        })
        ),
        tap(bookableEvent => {
          this.admService.setBookableEvents(bookableEvent);
        })
      )
  }
```

Note that in your snippet, you wrote `BookingDates` with a capital `B` and I believe this was not the intended behavior.

If you don't need to replace that null `bookableDates` with an empty array, you can remove the `map` entirely.

Comment: Thank you Octavian, it was the typo that was causing the problem.  Silly me.